# JavaCC: Matching with wildcard but not consuming for state switch

Tags: java, javacc

In JavaCC, for example in state `DEFAULT`, I want to perform a state switch, if the next token is `<A>`, I want to switch to state `STATE_A`, otherwise, I want to switch to state `STATE_B`.

I tried to use something like the following code with `""` as a wildcard:

```
TOKEN:
{
  <A: "aa"> : STATE_A
| <NOT_A: ""> : STATE_B
}
```

But it doesn't work, when a character that cannot be reduced to `A` is met, the function returns immediately, and doesn't get switched to `STATE_B`, therefore `""` doesn't seem to be able to do the job.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I find that this actually **works**.
The empty string will be matched when `A` cannot be matched, however we need to explicitly refer to `NOT_A` in the definitions of non-terminals. Therefore expressions like

```
[ <A> ]
```

should be rewritten as

```
( <A> | <NOT_A> )
```

to enforce a state switch.